# Fixed footer moves right when side-menu slides out

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive, bootstrap-5

I have a side-menu on the left, which expands from the left to the right on hover and also on a button click. Also, I have a footer which is fixed (on the bottom), my issue is when the side-menu expands, whole page content resizes but since footer is fixed, it moves on the right and goes out of the screen, buttons are not visible anymore. When i remove class which makes footer fixed, footer also resizes without going outside the screen but then it is not fixed.

What is the solution to resize fixed footer when the side-menu expands. I am using Bootstrap 5 in react.js typescript

I tried using bootstrap 5 rows and columns but since it works on a screen size, it does not give me the result

```
footer css code: 
.footer {   
position: fixed;   
bottom: 0;   
width: 92.5%;   
background-color: #fff; 
}
```

Comment: You can add the footer css with le "Edit" link under your question istead of adding a comment. It would help greatly that you share also the relevant part of code/css of how you make the left menu expand

Comment: You really should share more code for us to be able to help you, for your case my intuition tells me that making the footer a child of the resizable part (maybe a wrapper div will be needed) should be the key to solve your problem, but without the code I cannot tell how